# Proper way of adding a Segue on a TableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an application where the user selects a certain row in a TableView, and the contents of that Row will be sent to the next ViewController.

So far, I have connected the TableView Cell/Row to the next ViewController via a Segue. The issue I am facing right now is passing the value of the selected row to the next ViewController. I have written code for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and the `prepareForSegue` functions.

Here are the functions (In `ViewController.m` file, the one with the TableView):

The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath entered");

    //itemNameList is a mutable array where I get my TableView data from
    NSMutableString *itemName = [itemNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //selectedItem is a global mutable string I use to store the selected item to.
    selectedItem = itemName;
    UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Row Selected"
                             message:itemName
                             delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display Alert Message
    [messageAlert show];
}
```

The `prepareForSegue` function:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue entered");

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Details"])
    {
        //DetailViewController is the next ViewController once the user
        //selects an item
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        //the first selectedItem is a property of the second ViewController
        //the next selectedItem is the global mutable string
        detailViewController.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `prepareForSegue` function executes first before the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function. This is a huge issue because that means I don't actually get to pass the value to the second ViewController since the second ViewController has loaded into the screen already.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

My idea was to somehow get the Row the user selected in the `prepareForSegue` method but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The `prepareForSegue` seems to execute before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. So you would need to get selected row in `prepareForSegue`.

Use the method:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

Inside `prepareForSegue` to get selected row.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the connection you made in the IB between the `UItableViewCell` and the `ViewControllerB` and add a `segue` between `ViewControllera` to `ViewControllerB`.

Add:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextVC" sender:nil];
```

at the end of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

That way `prepareForSegue` will be triggered after `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` finished processing.

Answer (score 0):

In **prepare for segue**

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourIdentifier"]) {

    TheNextViewController *tnvc = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 //then do whatever you have to do
 //eg. set property in thenextviewcontroller by tnvc.propertyname = self..
```

Comment: The sender is a cell :)